# Repeating same SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a CASE statement in my SQL Server Stored Procedure. There I am repeeating a same long SQL statements every time for 11 CASEs. Should I put the SQL Statement in CASE condition in a another Stored Procedure? What could be the best approach?

```
CASE (SELECT ..................)
THEN  'SELCET a.field'
ELSE
 ''SELECT vlaues'
END
as 'Coulmn1 ' 

CASE (SELECT ..................)
THEN  'SELCET vaues'
ELSE
 ''SELECT vlaues'
END
as 'Coulmn1 '
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right :(  Can you use `select ... case when ... when ... else ...end`" instead?

Comment: @Arghya C - good question ;)  My point exactly :)

Comment: I have just tried to explain. It may not me syntactically correct. Problem is I am repeating a large SQL statement joining from 3-4 tables in CASEes. I want avoid the repeating the same SQL

Comment: don't think repeating the same query 11 times is a good idea, can't you store the result from the first execution and use it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like

```
SELECT
CASE (your select statement which retuns one value)
WHEN 'option1' THEN 'value2return1'
WHEN 'option2' THEN 'value2return2'
WHEN 'option3' THEN 'value2return3'
...
ELSE 'defaultValue'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use common table expressions [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
    WITH CTE (ColA)
    AS
    (
        Select ColA From Table
    )
    SELECT ColA
    FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE.  In the future it would help if you gave us a slightly better example of your code however.

```
WITH RepeateSelect AS (SELECT ..................)
.....
.....
CASE (SELECT * FROM RepeateSelect)
THEN  'SELCET a.field'
ELSE
 'SELECT vlaues'
END
as 'Coulmn1 ' 

CASE (SELECT * FROM RepeateSelect)
THEN  'SELCET vaues'
ELSE
 ''SELECT vlaues'
END
as 'Coulmn1 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the repeated query once thusly:

```
select A.C1, X.C2, X.C3
  from TableA as A inner join
    ( select B.AlmondJoy,
        case when B.YN > 7 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as C2,
        case when C.UD in ( -1, 1 ) then 'Up' else 'Down' end as C3
        from TableB as B inner join
          TableC as C on C.Id = B.Id
      ) as X on X.AlmondJoy = A.Zagnut
```